# How to slice only strings with digits at the end

Tags: angular, typescript, match, slice

I'm stuck in a problem. I have to slice the last two characters in a string, but only the strings that contain numbers.
I tried to use "nome": element.nome.slice(0,-2) and what I need is some kind of verification. But I can't find out how!

Here is my code:

```
      this.aux3.forEach(element => {        
        this.novasColecoes.push({
          "produtos": element.produtos,
          "nome": element.nome.slice(0,-2),          
          "referencia": element.referencia,
          "selecionado": false          
        });        
      })
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5EVdN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
const hasNumber = /\d/;

this.aux3.forEach(element => {        
    this.novasColecoes.push({
        "produtos": element.produtos,
        "nome": hasNumber.test(element.nome) ? element.nome.slice(0,-2) : element.nome,
        "referencia": element.referencia,
        "selecionado": false          
    });        
})
```

Comment: I thought about using the ternary operator, but every attempt didn’t work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// new function
 function isNumber(val) {
   return !isNaN(val);
  }

// You foreach

  this.aux3.forEach(element => { 
    let temp = element.nome;
    if(isNumber( temp )){
      temp = element.nome.slice(0,-2);
    }
        this.novasColecoes.push({
          "produtos": element.produtos,
          "nome": temp,          
          "referencia": element.referencia,
          "selecionado": false,
      
        });        
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following one line solution:

```
element.nome.split('').some(b => b.match(/\d/)) ? element.nome.slice(0,-2) : element.nome
```

First split the string by using split, this means we get an array of characters:

```
"test123".Split('');
// becomes
let splitString = ['t','e','s','t','1','2','3'];
```

We can then use the "some" array function on the new array. This returns a true boolean if some (any) of the conditions are true.

In our condition we use a regular expression (RegExp). "/\d/" this RegExp evaluates to "contains a digit". That's how we filter the digits.

```
// "match" returns true for 1, 2 and 3, so "some" returns true
var containsDigit = splitString.some(s => s.match(/\d/))
```

We then use a Ternary operator, if the condition is true, we return "element.nome.slice(0,-2)" otherwise we return the unmodified "element.nome"

```
{nome: containsDigit ? true : false}
```

Applied to your example:

```
this.aux3.forEach(element => {        
        this.novasColecoes.push({
          "produtos": element.produtos,
          "nome": element.nome.split('').some(n => n.match(/\d/)) ? element.nome.slice(0,-2) : element.nome,          
          "referencia": element.referencia,
          "selecionado": false          
        });        
      })
```

Comment: thanks a lot for you help, I really appreciate your explanation. It helped me  to understand how to approach this problem!